# what do SOMAXCONN mean in C socket programming?

Tags: c, sockets

I didn't understand anything about somaxconn in socket programming in C( Linux Ubuntu).I searched through several sites, but all those couldn't help me much.

```
listen(sockfd,SOMAXCONN);
```

Does this mean to listen concurrently to maximum no. of connected sockets?

Answer (score 22):

```
#include <sys/socket.h>

int listen (int socket, int backlog);
```

> The backlog argument provides a hint to the implementation which the implementation shall use to limit the number of outstanding connections in the socket's listen queue. Implementations may impose a limit on backlog and silently reduce the specified value. Normally, a larger backlog argument value shall result in a larger or equal length of the listen queue. Implementations shall support values of backlog up to `SOMAXCONN`, defined in `<sys/socket.h>`.
>
> If `listen()` is called with a backlog argument value that is less than 0, the function behaves as if it had been called with a backlog argument value of 0.
>
> A backlog argument of 0 may allow the socket to accept connections, in which case the length of the listen queue may be set to an implementation-defined minimum value.

As seen [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/listen).

Comment: For those that might need to easily remember what SOMAXCONN means, I think it's short for Socket Outstanding MAX CONNections. I could be mistaken, but it helps me remember anyway! :-)

Comment: Or more likely, and more consistent with other BSD Sockets #defines, SOcket MAXimum CONNections or SOcket MAXimum CONnection Number

Answer (score 14):

Simply put, the backlog is the maximum number of queued connections you want on a socket.. This queue is there so you can handle a connection from a client while others wait in line, the backlog specifies how long you want this line to be. if more clients attempt to connect to your server, more than the backlog, those connections will be dropped.

`SOMAXCONN` defines the maximum number you're allowed to pass to `listen()` which is `128` on my system.

You can read more about it in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/listen)

Comment: Those connections will be dropped by Windows. They will be ignored by other platforms, which will cause the client to retry a couple of times and then timeout if still no response.